# Use the same TestClass with different base class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, base-class, test-class

I am testing various servers,which has the same model, already tested by unit tests.
Now I want to test the real servers (not only general model).

When testing general model I created fake general server with fake adapter, which were defined in the base test class and all the testclasses inherit from it.This made more than hundred tests.

Now I need to use the same test classes but with various base classes(for various real servers). They use the same testing data and have the same results. They differ in some internal approach.

Is it somehow possible to call all the tests so many times as the count of servers is, everytime with different base test class(Server type and constructor)??

example:

```
[TestClass]
public class GeneralServerTests : BaseServer
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void IsAlive_ChecksInteraction_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(GeneralServer.Adapter.IsAlive());
    }
    ...
}
```

The Base test class

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class BaseServer
{
    protected Server GeneralServer;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        //here I assign the Server constructor,
    }
}
```

So i need to call the GeneralServerTests class with different Servers.

Hope you understand what i mean :)

any solution?

Comment: I get what you're trying to say, but generally unit testing should not involve a server in any way (apart, of course, from a build server). You should be testing code paths, not the server. If you can't something needs to be redesigned. If your logic is server dependent, perhaps you need some refactoring to make your server class more generic, with only a difference in connection strings. A sign that something is difficult or messy to test does not imply you aren't testing well enough, it implies the code under test isn't written well enough. It's not always true, but it's a fair assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it using

[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV",|DataDirectory|\ArchiveTestingData.csv", "ArchiveTestingData#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]

where all the needed info about the adapters are written.

Now all the tests run as many times as many adapters are in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you interpret inheritance using the "is" concept, reading the sentence: "GeneralServerTests **IS** a BaseServer", then that wouldn't seem to make much sense. So I think your test inheritance model probably needs a bit of review and refactoring.

Now, regarding running the same test against different inputs, you should at data-driven tests:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx

You can use a datasource to specify info about the target server, and configure your test code.